# The sitefinity Search widget does not enable searches inside content blocks

Tags: content-management-system, telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I'm trying to use the sitefinity search widget but it doesn't work correctly.
I've checked the "Static HTML in pages" option in search indexes page. I then reindexed it. The search result page doesn't display words which are in content blocks. Can you help me find a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with widgets breaking my indexing. [This post](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/search-widget-does-not-enable-searches-inside-content-blocks#8hzYhOxD8kKMECYTiIk9fQ), on the Sitefinity forums, outlines a way to determine if it's happening to you.

Comment: That post is mine. I didn't change anything in project I just re-indexed after a few days it's working. There is a bug but i didn't find it. Anyway It's working..